# Did Otto Lilienthal ever experiment with non-human-powered aircraft?

Tags: engineering-history, aerospace-engineering, aircraft-design

[Otto Lilienthal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Lilienthal), sometimes hailed as the first aviator, became famous for his many gliders, which pioneered new experiments in aeronautics. However, powered aircraft didn't take off - pun intended - until the Wright brothers successfully flew their powered airplane. Did Lilienthal ever experiment with non-human-powered flight? Wikipedia says he built a small engine, but doesn't say whether or not it was ever used in an aircraft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because just before posting it I found an answer.

[The Otto Lilienthal Museum](http://www.lilienthal-museum.de/olma/e213.htm) has a comprehensive list of Lilienthal's designs. One is listed as the "small wing-flapping machine." It didn't use a propeller (or jet engine, of course!) but instead used a small engine weighing about 22 pounds when fully fueled. Its wingspan was 22 feet, which was quite impressive. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Lilienthal) lists it as "Small Ornithopter." [Another page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopter) calls it the *kleiner Schlagflügelapparat*, which Google Translate translates to "small flapping wing apparatus."

[Here's](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Otto_is_going_to_fly.jpg) a picture of Lilienthal with it, pre-flight.

[image: Small ornithopter pre-flight]